# October CMS - send mail to members of backend group

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I've set up a group for a particular set of admin user's who need to be notified when new content is published.  Let's call this group 'notify-admins' for the sake of argument.

I have this code, taken from the October docs on for ([Users and Permissions](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/users))

```
Mail::sendTo(UserGroup::where('code', 'notify-admins')->get()->users, 'mailTemplate', $data);
```

However, this throws a `Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance` so clearlyI'm doing something wrong!

All I need to do is pop out an email to all members of the group - whats the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was doing this the wrong way around. Rather than query UserGroups I needed to look at Users who were members of groups.  This is code I ended up using to select the users within the target group and then iterate over them popping out emails.

```
$admins = User::whereHas('groups', function($query) {
   $query->where('code', 'notify-admins');
})->get();
```

Then to email...

```
foreach ($admins as $admin) {
    Mail::sendTo($admin->email, mailTemplate, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious to know where are you writing this code at? I am assuming a plugin registration file?

Here are two answers for you. The `where()` method is actually returning a collection of groups where 'code' is 'notify-admin'. In a better example where an item's price is $200; you could have multiple $200 items. If you wanted to access the `users` property in the collection you would either have to create a foreach loop (or for loop) or call the `first()` method.

In your case I think you could just call the `first()` method like so `$backend = UserGroup::where('code', 'notify-admin')->first()->users;` and try executing the mail send. I didn't test executing the email part because that is a whole other issue.

Here is some tips to diagnosing your problem and how I got my answer. Tip #1 Don't constrain yourself to the formula. I created a CMS Page and in there I put the section of code giving me errors:

```
function onStart() {
    $this['backend'] = UserGroup::where('code', 'moderator')->get()->users;
}
```

This gave me an error because it couldn't find UserGroup class. I had to add:

use \Backend\Models\UserGroup;

Next it gave me the error that you received. Tip #2 Understanding the objects you are working with. So I removed the `->users` to see what I am getting with just `->get()`. It turns out its a collection of models where 'code' = 'notify-admin'. Well that leads me to adding `first()`:

`$backend = UserGroup::where('code', 'notify-admin')->get()->first()->users;`

or this works as well

`$backend = UserGroup::where('code', 'notify-admin')->first()->users;`

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful - so I did as suggested, but I now get a "trying to get property of non object" error.



I'm working with a site I inherited from another company, they built quite an extensive plugin which extends a lot of Octobers features and I'm adding some new things at the client's request. The code is being added within an observer, inside the plugin folder.  Essentially, when content is saved it triggers this mail function as part of the 'saved' observer.  I'm new to October and Laravel, so it's proving to be a bit of a steep learning curve.

Comment: @Hill79 You didn't copy paste what I put without changing "notify-admin"?? I bet it is throwing "trying to get property of non object" error because `UserGroup::where('code', 'notify-admin')->first()` is returning null. So you can't call `->users` because null is not an object.

Comment: no, I altered the code to suit my needs.  I've found the solution now - I'll post an update